# ERC20 token conversion to ETH or USDC

Tags: tokens, ether, smart-contract-wallets

How can we convert ( via smart contract coding ) any erc20 token like BAT back to ETH or USDC ? I am very new to smart contract programming and I want to write the smart contract for the conversion. Can anyone please help with the logic I should start with for the conversion?

Comment: what do you mean by "convert"? like get the price of your ERC20 token in ETH or USDC? or swap your token for eth or usdc?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Uniswap in your contract, it's the most popular decentralized exchange, and you can view their documentation

https://uniswap.org/